# Residue coevoution from position wise residue preferences rather than multiple sequence alignments

Tags: proteins, sequence-analysis, mutations

Hello experts in residue coevolution analysis of proteins,

I am looking for a way to calculate residue coevolution (coupling scores) between all pairs of residues of a protein.
The issue is that rather than having a Multiple Sequence Alignment (MSA) which is used as an input by the relevant tools (e.g. evcouplings), I have position wise preferences for 20 amino acids for the protein.

For the protein with length `L`, I have a `20*L` matrix of position-wise preferences for amino acids.
I would like to use this matrix as a direct input for coevolution analysis.

Would it be possible to calculate the residue coevolution direcly from a residue preference matrix?

Any recommendation for a method of choice or a software tool would be helpful.

Comment: Coevolution requires you to know when you have residue X at position _n_ you will preferentially have Y at _m_. Namely the covariance of _n_ with _m_. If you have a PSSM matrix like you have, you cannot infer the covariance. You would need a `L*L*20*20` tensor.

Comment: However, your PSSM-like matrix contains useful information, such as what is core and what is surface. But I am not sure what tool uses it. Have a gander at https://predictioncenter.org/casp14/index.cgi